# What happens if the startdate of a CA is later that the startdate of a X509 certificate signed by it?

Tags: openssl, certificate-authority, x509

I am in the process of extending the lifetime of a private CA creating a new certificate with the same name, serial number, private/public keys, etc. The only change would be the "startdate" and "enddate".

Checking certificate chain verification, it is successful verifying an old X.509 certificate using the new CA, using OpenSSL. Cool.

But I wonder... the startdate of the new "equivalent" CA is more modern that the "startdate" of the X.509 certificate I am verifying. This would mean that the CA was not valid at the time of the X.509 certificate signing.

OpenSSL verifies that all the certificates in the certificate chain are valid "now", but it doesn't check "causality" between signatures in the certificate chain.

This is OK for OpenSSL, but I wonder if I would find issues with other X.509 libraries out there.

Checking RFC 5280 I see that chain validation is quite complex and not trivial, but the only time reference is this:

```
6.1.3. Basic Certificate Processing
...
  (2)  The certificate validity period includes the current time.
...
```

That is, all certificates in the chain must be valid "now", but causality between certificate signatures is not described at all.

So...

Am I safe doing what I am doing when dealing with other non "OpenSSL" implementations?

Answer (score 1):

It is not something uncommon when you have multiple CA certificates with same Subject and Public Key and different times. Here is a picture from the internet that shows such scenario:

[image]

If validation function has access to both (or multiple if any) CA certificates, it will build a separate chain for matching issuer and validate each independently. If we look to an image, then the following chains will be constructed:

1. Server cert -> LE Authority X3 -> ISRG Root X1
2. Server cert -> LE Authority X3 -> IdentTrust DST Root CA X3

Your scenario is very similar to `LE Authority X3` intermediate certificate. When all chains are constructed and validated, validation engine performs "best" chain selection based on certain criteria. In your case, for some time one chain will be valid and second will be invalid, so best chain selection is easy: validation function will use valid chain and discard invalid.

If validation function produced multiple valid chains, the function applies additional logic (or weights) in order to select "best" chain among multiple valid chains. That is, if validation function has access to both, valid and not-yet-valid issuers, then you shouldn't face any issues, because validation function will return a chain with valid issuer to the caller.

**UPDATE**:
it seems I didn't clearly understood the question which was about:

```
Is out there any problem if a CA "not before" is later that the "not before" of a certificate it signed?
```

it depends. If current (validation) time is within certificate's validity period, then it is considered time-valid. Let's say, you set CA validity from `Apr 1, 2024` to `Apr 1, 2025` and signed certificate is valid from `Mar 19, 2024` to `Jun 1, 2024`, then validation result will depend on when you run this validation.

1. You execute validation on `Mar 20, 2024`. Current time is within leaf cert's validity period. Leaf cert is ok. Current time is outside of issuer's validity period. Not all certificates are within their validity periods, chain is not time-valid and certificate validation function should fail.
2. You execute validation on `Apr 2, 2024`. Current time is within leaf cert's validity period. Leaf cert is ok. Current time is within issuer's validity period. Issuer is ok. All certificates are within their validity periods, entire chain is time-valid and validation function can proceed with other checks if necessary.

That is, retrospective certificate's time validity isn't checked at all. What matters -- if all certs are within their validity periods at validation time point. What was in the past -- no one cares.

And just to reiterate: it is valid scenario when leaf certificate's `NotBefore` is earlier than issuer's `NotBefore` or `NotAfter` is after issuer's `NotAfter` times. Leaf certificate contains only references of matching issuer cert, such as public key hash (via SKI extension) and Issuer field. No one prevents you to have multiple certificates with same public key (and hash) and Subject field. It happens all the time when you renew CA certificate with same key pair. During renewals, only serial number and validity periods are changed. Public key and Subject of the issuer is not changed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I think you are not replying the original question about signature timestamps and overlap of lifetimes of the different certificates in the chain.

Comment: There is no indication about signature timestamps in OP question, or I missed something? Certificate signatures are not timestamped.

Comment: My original question is about this: Is out there any problem if a CA "not before" is later that the "not before" of a certificate it signed? That would mean that the current CA certificate was not the certificate that originally signed the signed certificate?. Lets say, my "jcea.es" certificate has a "not before" of January 1st, but the CA signing it has a "not before" of "june" and we are in august. It is clear that that certificate was not the one signing the "jcea.es"

Comment: ` Is out there any problem if a CA "not before" is later that the "not before" of a certificate it signed?`, not if CA cert is within validity period at the validation time.

Comment: @jcea I've updated my response based on your comments. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: It does, Do you have any kind of best practices or validation rules describing that?. This is the behaviour of OpenSSL, but I am not sure it is mandatory and followed by any other X.509 implementation out there. Something authoritative like: "this is the way it is done". RFC 5280 is quite sparse about time verification. That is, you describe what I am seeing with OpenSSL, but I would be happier with a confirmation that that behaviour is actually mandatory to any compliant X509 validation suite.

Comment: `RFC 5280 is quite sparse about time verification` -- RFC is quite clear on this and you cited RFC in your initial post. Every certificate in chain is passed through the same logic and RFC requires that every certificate in a chain is within validity period at validation time.

Comment: It is also clear in 5280 (and 3280) but often missed that the anchor -- if it is a cert at all, which is not required -- doesn't need to be within its validityperiod. Both EE and chain certs _under_ the anchor must, but not the anchor. _Many_ programs including OpenSSL always use a cert, often a root cert, for the anchor and _do_ check its validityperiod, but some do not, notably Java. That is how LE used the _expired_ DST X3 for old Android -- but [**they are right now removing it**](https://letsencrypt.org/2023/07/10/cross-sign-expiration.html)